# Create Edit form with data from JSON url

Tags: json, angular, forms, edit

so I have a pre-populated Bootstrap form with a `Edit@` button, I now want to edit the content. It gets data from the JSON url created from the Firebase database. It has User model.The functions are in the `userprofile.component`.ts . Please advise.

**User Html page**

```
                <form class="needs-validation" novalidate >
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="first name" 
                     value={{useritem.firstname}} required> 
                        <div class="invalid-feedback"> 
                          Valid first name is required. 
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="last name" 
                     value={{useritem.lastname}} required> 
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Valid last name is required.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-toolbar float-right">
                 <button class="btn btn-info mr-1" (click)="updateUser();">Update</button> 
                  <button class="btn btn-dark " type="reset">Clear</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

**Firebase.service.ts**

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}


public getuserprofile() : Observable<User[]> 
{    
       return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.connectUrl);     
}

updateuserprofile( user: User): Observable<User> 
{
       return this.httpClient.put<User>(this.connectUrl, user);
}
```

**userprofile.component.ts**

```
         export class UserprofileComponent implements OnInit {

          useritem: any = [];


             constructor(private db: FirebaseService) { }


               ngOnInit() {

                  this.getUser();     

                }
                  getUser() {
                 this.db.getuserprofile().subscribe(result => 
                { 
                      this.useritem = result;
                       console.log(result);

                    });
                  } }
```

Comment: What advise you want

Comment: What do you want? Are you looking to populate your html page with your response data?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar I would like to know how to update the form in Angular to edit the values in JSON file.I am totally new to all these .

Comment: @MaruthiEranki The form is already populated with a get method, I want to edit the values.

Comment: Do you want to update values in client side? Can you show your sample JSON?

Comment: When I was editing your question, `userprofile.component.ts` have extra `}`. Please add your full code of `userprofile.component.ts`

Comment: @Kalana edited the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for. ex Reactive Forms :

```
<form  [formGroup]="form">
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <input formControlName="userName"  placeholder="first name" > 
   <input formControlName="userLastName"  placeholder="last name" > 
                </div></div>
                 <div class="btn-toolbar float-right">
             <button class="btn btn-info mr-1" (click)="updateUser();">Update</button> 
              <button class="btn btn-dark " type="reset" (click)="reset()">Clear</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

ts:

```
updateUser(){
  this.newUser = {
    userName: this.form.get('userName').value,
    userLastName: this.form.get('userLastName').value
  }
  console.log(this.newUser) //here you can make PUT to firebase
}
reset(){
  this.form.reset()
  this.newUser = {}

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ixedr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I am totally new to all these, so might be a silly question. I have a getUser() that already populates the form from the firebase realtime Json file. So I want to now edit \update the values, will that update the Json file as well? If yes, can you please help with more details.

Comment: If you want to edit /update the values, you have to make put/update request to your firebase

Comment: So you mean , changing the database in Firebase and not the Json file?